# for loop in bash lists dot and double dot folders

Tags: bash, files, wildcards, dot-files

```
for f in ~/common/.*; do
    echo $f
done
```

The entries listed are,

```
/home/sk/common/.           #undesired
/home/sk/common/..          #undesired
/home/sk/common/.aliasrc
```

And i am putting a ugly hack to skip processing `.` and `..` to avoid this,

```
if [[ $f  == '/home/sk/common/.' || $f  == '/home/sk/common/..' ]]; then
  true 
else
  --do the ops
fi
```

Is there a shell option that will hide the `dotted folders`? I am facing this problem with `ls -a` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a method using bash's `extglob`:

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in .!(|.); do
  echo "$f"
done
```

With `extglob` the pattern `!(pattern-list)` matches anything except for the given pattern. The pattern in the example says match everything that starts with `.` and is not followed by nothing or another single `.`.

Comment: hi jordan, this is the shell option, i was looking for... ., more notes on what does glob pattern .!(|.) do, will help....

Answer (score 3):

Did you mean:

```
ls -A
```

also you can use

```
ls -Al
```

This wont list the . and .. (its the capital A that does that). a will list all, and A will list almost all, almost all cause . and .. arent listed.

EDIT: The above is aimed at his second question, where he states he has the same issue with ls -a

Comment: Not very helpful in a script

Comment: true, however I mention this as he indicated that he had trouble with ls -a which is the second part of his question that no one else has answered. Its the very last sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Using `find`

```
find ~/common -type f -name ".*" -print0 | \
    while read -d $'\0' file; do \
        echo $file; \
    done
```

or with `find` and `IFS`

```
find ~/common -type f -name ".*" -print0 | \
    while IFS= read -rd '' file; \
        do echo $file; \
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your glob pattern (currently `*`), probably you are looking for `{[^.],.?}*`, so

```
for f in ~/common/.{[^.],.?}*; do
    echo "$f"
done
```

Comment: gives the entry `..?*` in the output in bash

Comment: the same result

Comment: @A.B. You probably don't have files which start from two dots as `..abc` in that directory. For example if you do `echo ???*` in empty directory bash prints `???*` instead of nothing. To overcome this set `shopt -s nullglob`.

Comment: I have two files: `.test` and `foo` and OP needs `.test`

Comment: No, OP needs all files which start from dot including two dots as `..abc`.

Comment: Yes, ok, but the output was annoying.

Comment: upvote for long-sufferring.

Answer (score 1):

The portable way to do this is with a `case` statement - and it doesn't hurt to trim the glob a little.

```
for f in ~/common/.?*; do
    case $f in (*/..)  ;; (*)
    : do something w/ "$f"
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`.*[!.]`

```
for f in ~/common/.*[!.]; do
    echo $f
done
```

Will give you all `.[...]foo` but not `.` and `..`

Addition: Here's for excluding symlink files:

```
for f in ~/common/.*[!.]; do
    [[ -L $f ]] || echo $f
done
```

.note: change `||` to `&&` if you want to echo only symlink files.

Comment: That won't match file `..abc` either.

Answer (score -2):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | while read f
do
ls -la "$f"
done
```

Comment: thanks Jodka, i am looking for the shell option that will help me to disable the listing of dotted folders, once for all...

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: That won't work if any of the filenames contain whitespace. (Though you could probably work around that by using the `IFS` (input field separator) variable and `find`'s `-print0` option.)

Comment: you are right. Same problem here? (not my solution)